# update props after use it

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm not good in react
but i code))
I have problem. My flow:
customer open "create new user" page -> then create user -> then redirect "Success" page.
after that when customer go to "create new user" page again, -> he go "Success" page without creating.
I know it is because i use props wrong way
how can I fix it?

my Component.js

```
class addUser extends Component {

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const user = {
            name: this.state.name,
        }
        this.props.newUser(user);
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
        const { isCreateNewUser } = this.props.isCreateNewUser;
        if(isCreateNewUser == true) {
            this.props.history.push('/')
        }
    }

    render() {
        <form className="add-new-post" autoComplete="off" onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
        </form>
    }
```

my reducer.js

```
export const reducerSubscriptions = function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                isCreateNewUser: action.payload
            }
    }
}
```

my action.js

```
export const newUser = (subscription) => dispatch => {
    axios.post('/api/user/add', subscription)
          .then(res => {
              dispatch({
                type: ADD_USER,
                payload: res.data
            });
          });
}
```

Comment: Are  you resetting your state after the user gets created?

Comment: i reset state but this.props.isCreateNewUser after create user always true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution:

my action.js

```
export const createUser = (user) => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/user/add', subscription); 
    dispatch({ type: SOME_ACTION_TYPE, payload: res });
    return res;
}
```

my Component.js

```
   this.props.createUser(user)
       .then(data => {
          if(data.data[0]){
               this.props.history.push('/');
           }
       }).catch(error => {
           console.log("error", error);
   })
```

i don't know is it good or not but it works.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

your problem seems like a props or state that don't return to his initial value
and

```
const { isCreateNewUser } = this.props.isCreateNewUser;
```

isCreateNewUser his an object? because when you destruct a non-object it should looks like this
const { isCreateNewUser } = this.props;
and where do you update isCreateNewUser to true

Comment: no no i have problem this.props.isCreateNewUser after create user always true

Comment: well if you update isCreateNewUser at redux you will get from redux that it always true
because you update there sp that state will stay true
try to do a state inside the component
that when you send to create it will cahge it to true and you will be redirect

Comment: redux is state management if every time you create something new and make isCreateNewUser to true and make it false it will render each time because of this